# Remove logs older than 90 day

Tags: ruby

I am writing a script that will zip up logs and remove anything older than 90 days on a Windows 2008 Server. I have come close by doing the following:

```
def remove_old_logs()
  d = Time.now.localtime.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
  tfile = "c:/slog/sec/Archive/#{d}-logs.zip"
  mtme=File.stat(tfile).mtime.to_s.split[0]

  # Compare the old mtime with the old and remove the old.
  Dir["c:/slog/sec/Archive/*"].each do |file|
    ntme=File.stat(file).mtime.to_s.split[0]
    FileUtils.rm( file ) if mtme > ntme #'Time.now.localtime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")'
  end
end
```

What would I have to do to get Ruby to do the Linux equivalent of:

```
find . -mtime +90 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Seems like it'd be easier to install Cygwin and just use the script.

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't understand your comment. Shouldn't ruby scripts that are not using internal shell functions in `` work OS independently? That's why he's writting a script, isn't it?

Comment: @shime The shell script.

Comment: @DaveNewton :D I don't consider a one liner a script. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a somewhat idiomatic Ruby way that is OS independent,

```
require 'date'

module Enumerable
  def older_than_days(days)
    now = Date.today
    each do |file|
      yield file if (now - File.stat(file).mtime.to_date) > days
    end
  end
end

# Example emulating `find /path/to... -mtime +90 -type f -exec rm {} \;`
Dir.glob('/path/to/your/files/**/*').older_than_days(90) do |file|
  FileUtils.rm(file) if File.file?(file)
end
```

Note use of [Dir.glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob)'s `**` to match recursively.

(Incidentally you might consider in shell, `find . -mtime +90 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm` to be more efficient and avoid the [separator problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#The_separator_problem))

Answer (score 1):

What is it your script isn't doing that you want? The only significant thing I see that is missing is the test to see if it's a file or directory, `-type f` in the `find` command.

```
File.file?('path/to/file')
```

The only other thing is the test to see if it's older than 90 days, but you should be able to figure that out easily enough.

Comment: I was able to come up with a way of calculating whether the file was 90 days old by doing the following:
    # Define age limit and calculate the difference in seconds
      old_files_age = 7776000
      ctime = Time.now
      past_due_logs = (ctime - old_files_age).to_s.split[0]
Everything worked perfectly after I defined these variables and calculated the difference.